# Vue3: Controlling checkbox checked state by a component prop

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs3

This is the setup:

**Parent component:** Has a reactive Todo object with a checked state `{checked: true` and passes it to a `Todo` component.

**Todo component:** Accepts the Todo as a prop and binds the `checked` value to a checkbox. Upon toggling the checkbox, it emits an event to the parent, which then asynchronously updates the `checked` state of the Todo.

**Parent:**

```js
<template>
  <Todo @update="handleUpdate" :todo="todo" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import Todo from "./components/Todo.vue";

let todo = reactive({ checked: true });

let handleUpdate = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Always sets it to false for test purposes
    todo.checked = false;
  }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

**Child**:

```js
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxProxy" />
</template>

<script setup>
const { computed, defineProps, defineEmits } = require("vue");

let props = defineProps(["todo"]);
let emit = defineEmits(["update"]);

let checkboxProxy = computed({
  get() {
    return props.todo.checked;
  },
  set(val) {
    emit("update", val);
  },
});
</script>
```

**Question:** I would expect the checkbox to get unchecked a second after it has been checked. But that doesn't happen. Why?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snow-kdse27

I also tried this setup:

```js
<input type="checkbox" :checked="todo.checked" @change="emit('update)" />
```

But it still not reflecting the todo state. I'm testing in Brave it that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the `todo` object itself but just the HTML element. Meaning, once the state is set to false it is not updated to true when you emit the event.
And because you use reactive and computed the state is cached, so nothing will happen until something is changed.

```js
let handleUpdate = (e) => {
// actually changing the state here
todo.checked = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Always sets it to false for test purposes
    todo.checked = false;
  }, 1000);
};
```

`todo.checked = true` is going to change the state and after one second (in your case) it is going to be set back to false, which respectively will update the props and the checkbox itself.

**Updated:**

To update the checkbox based on the response you can either:

1. prevent the default action and update if needed (when the response is ready).

Todo.vue

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="props.todo.checked" @click.prevent="emit('update', $event.target.value)" />
    <div>Prop value: {{ todo }}</div>
  </div>
```

2. Update the state before the response, and then set the data from the response if there is a change as in the example from above.

If I'm not mistaken, using `Vue.set()` in vue 2 actually will result in the same (visual) behavior as pt2

Keep in mind that both ways are not very UX-friendly.

Comment: Ooooh.... Of course, that makes perfect sense. Background: I was rewriting a Vue 2.x app, where the updated `todo` object was updated within an array via `Vue.set()`. This did actually work. But yeah - now, since technically nothing changes on the data side, the component is not being rerendered. But what would be the idiomatic way to "force" a rerender after updating an object, even it the object might stay the same? So basically the equivalent of `Vue.set()` in Vue3?

Comment: @Quasdunk well, `Vue.set()` was used to update complex objects and arrays since vue 2 uses `observable`. On the other hand, vue 3 now uses `proxy` so in most cases you won't need `Vue.set()`, meaning you can update a complex object/array and still get the reactivity as long as the change happens. [This might help](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue)

Comment: Another thing is that in Vue 2 since the object was part of the array, the only thing vue 2 would see is the array of objects (not the objects' props). So Vue.Set() is the way to update an object's property within a collection and trigger the array's attached reactivity. Now you can either `watch` for changes or create a `reactive` prop.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have quite a decent concept of Vue's reactivity system. But the use case is: The `handleUpdate` method actually fires off an ajax request and asks the server to do the update. The server then returns the **whole** updated `todo` object, and I then replace it with the client side one. But: If something went wrong and no update happened, the object technically looks the same client side, even though it's a completely new one. And I want that update to be reflected no matter what. So basically I want to rerender when the actual object itself changes, not just the structure.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Ok, I will update the answer in a proper way.

Comment: Updated. And If I may suggest - if it is possible, you can update the state and if something goes wrong, just notify the user about that, but keep the state updated. That way the user will have the possibility to try again with whatever option they have selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, that actually seems to work, but hooking into click event or updating random object properties just for the sake of it feels kind of hacky. I guess it's fine in this use case, but I can see it breaking down pretty quickliy in more complex use cases. Totally agree on the UX part though. Further feedback is being handled for sure, but it would be nice if I at least didn't have to care about the checkbox input - just like it worked with `Vue.set()`. Anyway - thanks a lot for your time and effort, I really appreciate it!

Comment: For future reference: What I landed on is a local checked state that I bind the checkbox to, an a `watch` on the `todo` prop that updates the local state when the prop changes. `watch` seems to pick up on the changed object reference, probably because the whole object is watched, while the computed `get` function only watches the value of a property on that object. Still feels a little hacky, but at least this way I can stick with v-model instead of dealing with the click event or jiggling object props just to trigger a rerender.